# Faced a problem whiling getting Ethereum transactions which are in mempool

Tags: ethers.js, pending-transactions, web3-providers, txpool

I am trying to get mempool transactions ASAP.
My purpose is to get the pending transactions on Uniswapv2 router before the transaction is confirmed.

I tried several providers from Quicknode, Alchemy, Infura and Rivet.
And also I tried with localnode and Blocknative API.
Ofc, I can get the pending transactions hash's using those providers and API. But after receive it, I can see that the receiving time is always after the transaction confirmation.

For example: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x362397df699548b52d9819b20170053cf45897742c1d2428acdf8005f93f766d

I received this transaction on Aug-30-2022 04:59:25.
But it is already confirmed on Aug-30-2022 04:59:14.
Same thing is happening with most of the transactions.
I want to receive these transaction hashes about 5 seconds ago.

If someone help me with this, it would be very helpful!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can get the pending transactions using [Chainstack's](https://chainstack.com/) WSS Node.

In your code, you first need to declare a provider

```
// Connecting to the Chainstack's WSS Node
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
  "WSS_NODE_HERE"
);
```

Then, if you want to want to get the pending transactions, you can use the below code.

```
provider.on("pending", (tx) => {
  provider.getTransaction(tx).then(function (transaction) {
    console.log(transaction);
  });
});
```

Here is how the response should look like:

```
{
  hash: '0xda4b05e28cccb82fd679b55373397628d046584a129fd8b57f3f73426f4bb1a8',
  type: 0,
  accessList: null,
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  transactionIndex: null,
  confirmations: 0,
  from: '0x250ABd1D4EBC8e70a4981677D5525f827660bDE4',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x47c78e2153', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x07a120', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0x886ccA828224F2D196aD386F35A76573604702c2',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 14310051,
  data: '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',
  r: '0xa2575d515a9c4bcb9b473c4cc827343f2e499d6e8e549e6b5f34db2ec17e689a',
  s: '0x1a35e96ae6e7e71896ef3c57927c1087d84164fb714e6fa3b0f40cc54534d69a',
  v: 310,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 137,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
{
  hash: '0x7bde2f94d638af4d2aff1177f77cb27b7502d0a11b703ce10f12b3a282b573d0',
  type: 0,
  accessList: null,
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  transactionIndex: null,
  confirmations: 0,
  from: '0x67631470bE83F7b449d2efc4A03dad3aEe779D1B',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x288aa092c9', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x0f4515', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0xe6E7D667b5234748eA264D3Fa7Dd8B4C3883Dafc',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 40684,
  data: '0x7898e0c20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002baf7c2600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000630dc4c30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007444f542f55534400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  r: '0x6fd11697c57b23d46e684df78310c4e5f6a862a2ce845cfd3d872d8f328665cd',
  s: '0x47797e0ee8e2a551e6fdc91242e4c0068a2db59dd7cf33bb7b55cac605c291ba',
  v: 310,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 137,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
{
  hash: '0x9e52869044bb2f6b77350b485295e9759c9d874df06744c6f25229d2fa098b45',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  transactionIndex: null,
  confirmations: 0,
  from: '0x27f2CC189c6718C6338B6e97244741f9245383Bb',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x2e90edd000', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x1ae4562300', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x2e90edd000', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x0f3e58', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0xBaF13c00BdBc3a752715E3a8B7684896871Ae7B4',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 79,
  data: '0xd96a094a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  r: '0x346dbc10bbe727ffe4d75a03dcae77e6a96bb1031ca4ed184ba60c96a0270d19',
  s: '0x6790c4ad217c93267f25990ce230e9e7b2ae2e8b2defc951d5854984d3e01130',
  v: 0,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 137,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
{
  hash: '0x72cc29b66331102772dc8d0f73bace8390ee735013b4f0de592f516e80d26c07',
  type: 0,
  accessList: null,
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  transactionIndex: null,
  confirmations: 0,
  from: '0xa1ab1c841898Fe94900d00d9312ba954e4F81501',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x570007a669', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x07a120', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0xa0EEfe4dA82d88991c26a2bA7868c5a1C485A72E',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
  nonce: 13736334,
  data: '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',
  r: '0xfbf6b9de4e9f02c85bae9d1d8180d71100cca3d4072aaf3818b935d5ad77bfb9',
  s: '0x2fcca174587b07d889a0a2fd4826a8db978ee4f4e7a87d185067b84171ee432c',
  v: 310,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 137,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

The above code is to get the pending transactions (i.e: not yet confirmed from EVM, but the process should be similar with Uniswap too)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Suhail. But I used this code before posting this and it's not working good.

Comment: Take a look at this repo: https://github.com/suhailkakar/evm-pending-transactions

I have built a simple Next.js app that fetches all the pending transactions from EVM : ) 

btw, it would be great if you share the piece of code that you are using.